# How do i make a process state always on for elixir?

Tags: concurrency, process, elixir, pid

I have a simple program that when given a tupple message containing {pid,integer} will send a message back to the processor with its PID and the interger+1. The problem is that I need this program to be left active so i can send it multiple messages, and then when i flush() it, will send back its mailbox all at once. It only works 1 message at a time. I tried a recursion but it doesn't work. Here is what I have.

```
defmodule Spawner do
  def start() do

    spawn(fn ->
      receive do
        {pid,y} -> send(pid,y+1)
        Spawner.start()
      end
    end)

  end
end
```

Then on the terminal i would do:

```
> x = Spawner.start()
> send x, {self(),3}
> send x, {self(),5}
> flush()
#⇒ output: {PID,4}
```

I need the output to be `{PID,4}` and `{PID,6}`.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Think about `send` as about ping-pong game. The rule is: one send ⇒ one consume. Exactly as in ping-pong one can not expect the proper behaviour from the opposite side, serving ten balls at once.

To accomplish what you want you are going to have a `GenServer` that *collects* all the received messages (instead of immediately *answering* to each of them.)

Also it would provide, say, `get_all` call, that would retrieve all the collected messages from it’s state and respond with the `{int, list}` tuple:

```
{PID, [msg1, msg2, ..., msgN]}
```

The implementation of that won’t fit the margins here, but since you have your question tagged with [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), [`GenServer`](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/genserver.html) tutorial would be a good start. Then you might want to read about [`Agent`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Agent.html) to hold the state.

---

Other way round (I do not recommend it) would be `flush()` the consumer recursively with a timeout. The empty queue would trigger a timeout. But, again, it’s not how it’s supposed to be done, because you probably want all the already sent messages to be collected somehow on the other side.